# Why does the Mind Stone still affect Vision after Shuri spent all that time separating it?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Shuri was tasked with separating the mind stone from Vision, and was doing it during the Wakanda battle with Proxima Midnight, Cull Obsidian, and the Outrider army.

[image: Shuri separating Mind Stone from Vision]

Mid way, we see her get interrupted during the process and she starts making large sweeping motions with her arms, which indicates to me, that she was going a lot faster than she felt comfortable, then shuts it down to turn and face the interruption.

At this point, the mind stone should be relatively (50%? 70%?) disconnected, so how does Thanos end up killing Vision (or appears that he has killed Vision)?

Answer (score 13):

**There's a big difference between partially *disconnected* and ripped out of one's head forcibly.**

The point of Shuri's procedure was to *carefully* unlink the Stone from the Vision without doing any damage.

As Shuri says:

> ...there are more than two trillion neurons here.
>
> One misalignment could cause a cascade of circuit failures.

**As we know this process was not completed**

However, Thanos didn't care about the damage he would inflict and **ripped** it from the Vision's head causing incredible harm.

If you want a very basic comparison, consider removing a hard drive from a PC....sure if you unclipped a couple of cables you'd be partly done, but if someone else the ripped open the PC box with an axe and tore out the drive....it'll ruin the PC.

[image]

Comment: The analogy of the hard drive doesnt work so well... If that hard drive was one of four (Stark, Banner, Jarvis, Mind Stone) as Banner conjectured, might not cause a problem.  If we look at the physicality of it, was Vision being run entirely by the Mind Stone?  People can get a partial lobotomy and still function... others with epilepsy have had the middle bridge between left and right hemispheres physically separated (done to withhold propagation of seizures) and can conduct normal lives.

Comment: When the proposal was put forth about separating the Mind Stone, I imagined Vision simply falling back to a Jarvis mind-set, possibly with a lot less self awareness or instigating thoughts, and being more reactive like an AI typically is.

Comment: ...and they don't separate entire hemispheres using a pickaxe....and as I said it was a **basic** analogy...not meant to be taken literally.

Comment: Granted.  I'm trying to point out a what looks like a plot hole, or maybe it isn't.  The analogy of a hard drive could work, if the mind stone were the only thing powering Vision's intelligence is my point.

Comment: @enorl76 "People can get a partial lobotomy and still function" Perhaps, but those people did not have their skulls crushed and the brain forcibly ripped apart. (I'm sure there are exceptions, but those are still major traumas that would surprise no one if the person had died.) It was delicately removed via scalpel with protective and repetitive efforts planned and executed. That would be what Shuri is doing. Thanos, on the other hand, is doing something more akin to breaking it out with a jackhammer, as shown in the image.

Comment: *repetitive --> reparative

Comment: If you turn off a computer, unplug the hard drive, and remove it, the computer (and the hard drive) will be fine. If you smash open the case and rip out the hard drive while it's still powered up, you may very well short out and destroy the whole system.

Comment: Either way Vision was kinda disappointing. “Tony, you lost another super bot?” was quite funny.

Comment: @jpmc26, transorbital lobotomy was done by inserting a pick through the eye socket and turning a few times. That was not a delicate operation (and Phineas Gauge survived having his skull pierced in an accident that also damaged his brain, so even that is possible). I am not sure if this has any bearing on the answer, but you really should not imagine psychosurgery as a particularly benign or delicate procedure.